# How many objects are created after more than 1 assignments?

Tags: python

This is in Python.

```
a = 1
a = 10
```

2 assignments to a. Is 2 objects created?
What happen to the '1' after '10' is assigned to a?

Comment: Please define what is an object for you. IMHO, `1` is an integer *value*. Read the documentation of Python, in particular [§3 Data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html). Also, download then study the open source [code of Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/) and read *books* on [Garbage Collection](http://gchandbook.org/)

Comment: It goes bye bye. https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-delete-variables-and-functions-from-memory-in-python#:~:text=Python%20automatically%20deletes%20variables%20and,used%2C%20freeing%20the%20memory%20used.&text=This%20can%20be%20useful%20when,free%20memory%20for%20other%20uses.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do you mean Python objects in the language or do you mean CPython objects in the interpreter? If you mean the former, yes, everything is an object. If you mean the CPython interpreter, that's an implementation detail but yes, it will hit up the heap I'd imagine. A big part of the reason Python is so slow is that everything, even just making a number is a heap allocation, whereas in C you have the luxury of stack access, locality, packing, primitives.... (hence NumPy...).

Comment: okay thank you... just to double check if
``` 
a = 1
a = 2
a2 = True
```
A total of 3 python objects are created?

Comment: Check out [this](https://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-integer-objects-implementation/) -- CPython batch allocates integers to avoid overhead, but there's still heap access time costs.

Answer (score 0):

when your declare `a = 1` python creates a variable `a` pointing to the location in memory where stored `1`, again when you declare `a = 10` it creates other object pointing to the **new location on memory**. it doesn't override the old one and still keeps that.
as an `example`

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> a = 1
>>> aid = id(a)
>>> aid
9062624
>>> a = 10
>>> aid2 = id(a)
>>> aid2
9062912
>>> ctypes.cast(aid, ctypes.py_object).value
1
>>> ctypes.cast(aid2, ctypes.py_object).value
10
```

it shows it create a new object and points to that, while the old object is remained.

Comment: so... 2 objects created?

Comment: It's much more like `lists` when you define a new value the variable **points** to the new value, while the last object is still `remaining`(mean you still have the that pointer, pointing to that location in memory)

Answer (score -1):

The variable is used to hold some value that can be used by the program. when any variable holds some value and the user will change the value from a new value, then that variable will hold the new value and the old value will erase or be changed to a new value.

So here,the first assignment a=1 is erased or lost when second assignment a=2 is evaluated. And therefore 'a' stores 10 and 1 is discarded.

Since both the values are pointing to same object a, there is only one object.